# How to distinguish between "image not available" and "not authorized" with `docker pull`?

Tags: docker, openshift

I need to wait for the presense of an image in an OpenShift external docker repository.  Currently I am looking at trying to pull it every X seconds.

```
docker pull foo/bar/fum
```

Unfortunately both `Error response from daemon: Get .../manifests/latest: unauthorized: authentication required` and `Error response from daemon: name unknown` sets exit code 1 so I cannot easily distinguish them.

How should I approach this?

Comment: If the image is part of OpenShift, why not use `oc get imagetag`?

Comment: Can't you grep the different outputs? `OUTPUT=$(docker pull foo/bar 2>&1); if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then echo $OUTPUT | grep -q "unauth" && echo "NOT AUTHORIZED"; echo $OUTPUT | grep -q "unknown" && echo "CONTAINER IMAGE NOT AVAILABLE"; fi`

Comment: @WillGordon Does that work with the external registry?  I am still learning everyday with openshift and this command is new to me)

Comment: @Marcel That puts in a subtle dependency on humanly readable strings that may change over time, that I would preferably avoid if possible.  If nothing else is possible I may have to though.

Comment: Using output redirection from docker cmds in my experience is not as straightforward as I expected too. I guess using a docker library would be your safest bet, something like https://github.com/docker/docker-py

Comment: What do you mean by "external registry"? Is the OpenShift internal registry that just happens to be available externally...or is it just a regular Docker registry running on OpenShift? If it's the latter, then you're correct, there would be no `oc` commands that can be used.

Comment: @WillGordon I do not know the details, except it is NOT an internal registry.  This is a docker registry binding two Openshift instances together (being the only thing available to us that is visible to both).  Docker can log into it.  It titles itself "RED HAT CONTAINER REGISTRY" in the web gui.

Comment: Ok, so then if you only have `docker` access to it, you'll be stuck parsing `docker` stuff. Sorry :/